# Angular 4 + Spring boot + Spring Security: Getting browser authentication popup

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing my first Angular project. Now I have been asked to implement LDAP security in the application. So after I followup [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) and [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/), I can see the login screen and it does also validate against AD. But the problem is I am seeing a browser authentication popup. I am not sure if it is Angular or spring security configuration issue. Any please would be great!
[image]

WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);
    LdapConfiguration ldapConfig;
    ActiveProfilesConfiguration activeProfiles;
    SecurityUserConfiguration securityUser;
    SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(LdapConfiguration ldapConfig,
                                    ActiveProfilesConfiguration activeProfiles,
                                    SecurityUserConfiguration securityUser,
                                    SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {
        this.ldapConfig = ldapConfig;
        this.activeProfiles = activeProfiles;
        this.securityUser = securityUser;
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
      //  .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/home", "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

app.module.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class XhrInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const xhr = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
    });
    return next.handle(xhr);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Spring judging from it running on spring's default port 8080.

Comment: Spring security: 4.2 and Spring Boot: 1.5.3

Comment: @Phil: Do you mean if I change the port to something else, there would be any popup?

Comment: Hey you asked me to have a look at this question because I answered a similar question for spring-boot and angular 1.x. unfortunately I'm not very familiar with later angular versions, but this answer looks like what you wanna do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465070/2576531 . It shows how to add a Header to every request. You could use your browser tools to verify that the request that gets the 401 response contains the X-REQUESTED-WITH header

Comment: @dur: My home screen is a dashboard screen and I have navvar in dashboard as well. S I have login hyper link in navbar. On click of Login link, I see my Login page. But here my query is why the browser authentication is popping up?

Comment: 1) Yes, my login page is from angular. 2) Yes, the popup appears first time when I load the page. Once I enter username/password, that browser popup doesn't come again.

Comment: @SK. You configured `.httpBasic()`, therefore you get the browser popup to enter username and password. If you want to load your page without authentication you have to `permitAll` your page. Or if you want authentication, you have to add the `Authentication` header to your request, see  Yannic Klem's comment.